# How can I click a tag inside of clickable div(ng-click) without clicking the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Here is the code:

```
<div ng-click="grid.appScope.navToPage(row)"class="ui-grid-cell" ui-grid-cell style="cursor: pointer">
   <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
     <a ng-href="/mywebpage/2" target="_blank">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span>
     </a>
   </div>'
</div>
```

I want to figure out some way to be able to click the a tag link without clicking the div with the `ng-click`. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549840/jquery-keep-a-link-clickable-in-clickable-div

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can prevent click propagation using the `$event.stopPropagation()` which is available on many angular directives such as `ng-click`. Please have a look at this question [AngularJS ng-click stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation)

In your case, the anchor tag should look like this:

```
<a ng-href="/mywebpage/2" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" target="_blank">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<a ng-href="/mywebpage/2" target="_blank" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></a>
```